# eclipse stops at breakpoint, but no debug features available

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Yet another eclipse breakpoints question, I would argue this is different and undiscussed as of now. If that's not the case, point me to the right question.

I'm running eclipse kepler in the debug perspective. I can set breakpoints and eclipse *does* stop at them. However, absolutely no functionality of the debug perspective is made available. The code has simply stopped. I know this is the case as when I remove the breakpoint, the code resumes its processing.

More details - no green stripe on the breakpointed line, no step in/step over/step out, no pause/resume/ or even stop buttons are available. Only the red box on the Console tab are available.

Eclipse simply pauses execution and does not inform you, nor allows you to resume either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was typing this question, it occurred to me that I had fixed this a couple times before.

If you navigate to Window -> Show View -> Debug

A debug tab will be displayed, showing the current threads. It appears that eclipse will not avail the functions of step in/step over/step out/pause/resume/stop, showing a green stripe of where you are breakpointed, or using the display tab to look at different variable values.

I think this is quite confusing as eclipse does not give you any clue or hint to open that debug tab.

I finished typing this out in hopes that someone else may stumble upon it, and it may help them. Also for the next time I have this problem and forget what I did.

Comment: After two years I stumbled upon the same problem and solved it because of your answer. Many thanks!